# Changing the format of excel turns file in to insane size

Tags: vba, excel

I Just change format of sheets using a vba code and the file turns insanely large and increases by ~200 MB. If I do it using excel interface , nothing like this happens but I want to use the code.

```
Function ReturnName(ByVal num As Integer) As String
    ReturnName = Split(Cells(, num).Address, "$")(1)
End Function     

lcol = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 1 To lcol
If (ws1.Cells(4, i) = "Date") Then
ws1.Range(ReturnName(i) & "5" & ":" & ReturnName(i) & "1000").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
Else
ws1.Range(ReturnName(i) & "5" & ":" & ReturnName(i) & "1000").NumberFormat = "0"
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Is it acceptable in your scenario to format the entire colum(s) instead of 996 cells in the column? That should make a huge difference... meaning smaller file size.

Comment: You've only shown us a portion of the code so I have to ask if it is possible that you have placed an errant value into a rogue 'last cell' (like `Z1048576`). Where does `Ctrl+End` take you on the worksheet? What does `Debug.Print ws1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address(0, 0)` report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for example:

```
ws1.Range(ReturnName(i) & "5").EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

Comment: I realize that the OP holds the ReturnName function in a certain 'coolness' but couldn't that code be simplified to `ws1.Columns(i).NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"`?

Comment: I though I'd pick one thing to teach in this case. Excel stores number formats once for entire rows or entire columns or entire groups of those things (including the entire sheet), as opposed to once for each cell for smaller ranges. The focus here was to teach that and so I wanted to include EntireColumn for emphasis. Bypassing ReturnName is certainly better, but might muddy the lesson.

Comment: Is that just for numberformats? or do other things like color highlights work the same way.  I've always thought that applying a color highlight to a whole column made the file bigger than just a selection of cells in the column.  Edit: Scrub that, I just tested it and whole columns or rows is more effecient.  I think perhaps that wasn't the case in older versions of excel, that or i'm going senile.

Comment: It's always been this way.